# linux bottom-half preemption

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

As far as I know there are many mechanisms to implement bottom-halves in Linux:

- softirq
- taslket
- workqueue
- threaded irq ( request_threaded_irq() )

Which all have their characteristics regarding schedulability.
What I cannot get from the literature is their *preemption* possibility. What kind of tasks can preempt the various different bottom-half implementations?

More specifically, I am interested in threaded irqs and workqueues. How much can one be confident that once scheduled a threaded irq or a workqueue is not preempted before completion i.e. runs in one shot? What are the types of tasks that are able preempt them?

For example, Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love states that only top-halves can preempt softirqs, so I would say that softirqs complete in one shot most of the times (or if they get preempted, it's only for a very short time).

My goal is to qualitatively assess the time between two operations in the same threaded irq or workqueue. In particular the time between i2c data read and a reading of the system clock.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Worqueues and threaded IRQ handlers are run in a process context and can be preempted. When they can be preempted actually depends on your kernel configuration (`CONFIG_PREEMPT` or `CONFIG_PREEMPT_VOLUNTARY`) and also on the realtime priorities you set on the handling thread.

You can not assume that your workqueue or your bottom half will not get interrupted. This means that if you share resources with a top half, you have to use proper locking.